# HTML different focus direction to only one part of the page

Tags: html, css

im trying to give only one part of the html different focus direction - 
my whole page in RTL - hebrew 
and im building a time line that must go from LTR when im tabbing 
but it goes RTL instead.
because im making this website for disabled people, the option using keyboard TAB must go in the logic direction for them.

for me its starts RTL like this :
[image]

i tried tabindex but that means i need to give this to every part of the page 
(over 100 tabindex for all the elements).
i tried dir = ltr in the table - nothing.
i need it to start LTR from 1907.
any ideas ?

```css
#historyLine td {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 25px;
  float: right;
  margin: -17px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table dir="ltr">
  <tr id="historyLine">
    <td id="year2018"><a tabindex="0" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-placement="bottom" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="שנת 2018" data-content="מאז 'פוקימון' ועד היום האנימה ממשיכה לצבור פופולאריות בכל העולם וגם בישראל. עד היום יצאו מעל ל35,000  סדרות אנימה! ">2018</a>
      <td id="year1999"><a tabindex="0" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-placement="top" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="שנת 1999" data-content="‘פוקימון'! הדבר הראשון שצץ לראש זה היצורים החמודים האלה! הסדרה הזו צברה פופולאריות והפכה למשחק קלפים משחק מחשב ועוד. היא פרצה את הדרך לאנימות בחו‘’ל ובעיקר באמריקה. ">1999</a></td>
      <td id="year1974"><a tabindex="0" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-placement="bottom" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="שנת 1974" data-content="‘ספינת החלל יאמוטו' - זוהי סדרת אנימה האופרה הראשונה מסוגה. הסדרה נוצרה בהשראת הצלחת סדרת סרטי מלחמת הכוכבים.">1974</a></td>
      <td id="year1961"><a tabindex="0" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-placement="top" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="שנת 1961" data-content=" 'היסטוריה מיידית' – זהו שמה של האנימה הראשונה ששודרה ביפן. כמו השם שלה, הסדרה לימדה ילדים על היסטוריה. ">1961</a></td>
      <td id="year1946"><a tabindex="0" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-placement="bottom" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="שנת 1946" data-content="אוסמו טזוקה בן ה17 יצר את האנימה היפנית הראשונה אי פעם. לאנימה קוראים 'יומנו של מא-צ'אן'.">1946</a></td>
      <td id="year1907"><a tabindex="0" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-placement="top" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="שנת 1907" data-content="האנימציה הראשונה בעולם נוצרה! היא ארכה רק 3 שניות בהן מלח מוריד את הכובע שלו.">1907</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: you can not use display: inline-block and float: Right in the same element, it does not make sense to do it either.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've messed up LTR, RTL, float:right and default document flow... 
Please play with the snippet bellow, I believe it does what you want.

```css
body {
  direction: rtl
}

table {
  direction: ltr
}

#historyLine td {
  direction: rtl;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

[data-toggle=popover] {
  position: relative
}

[data-toggle=popover]:focus::after {
  content: attr(data-content);
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 10px;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id="historyLine">
    <td id="year1907"><a tabindex="0" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-placement="top" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="שנת 1907" data-content="האנימציה הראשונה בעולם נוצרה! היא ארכה רק 3 שניות בהן מלח מוריד את הכובע שלו.">1907</a></td>
    <td id="year1946"><a tabindex="0" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-placement="bottom" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="שנת 1946" data-content="אוסמו טזוקה בן ה17 יצר את האנימה היפנית הראשונה אי פעם. לאנימה קוראים 'יומנו של מא-צ'אן'.">1946</a></td>
    <td id="year1961"><a tabindex="0" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-placement="top" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="שנת 1961" data-content=" 'היסטוריה מיידית' – זהו שמה של האנימה הראשונה ששודרה ביפן. כמו השם שלה, הסדרה לימדה ילדים על היסטוריה. ">1961</a></td>
    <td id="year1974"><a tabindex="0" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-placement="bottom" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="שנת 1974" data-content="‘ספינת החלל יאמוטו' - זוהי סדרת אנימה האופרה הראשונה מסוגה. הסדרה נוצרה בהשראת הצלחת סדרת סרטי מלחמת הכוכבים.">1974</a></td>
    <td id="year1999"><a tabindex="0" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-placement="top" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="שנת 1999" data-content="‘פוקימון'! הדבר הראשון שצץ לראש זה היצורים החמודים האלה! הסדרה הזו צברה פופולאריות והפכה למשחק קלפים משחק מחשב ועוד. היא פרצה את הדרך לאנימות בחו‘’ל ובעיקר באמריקה. ">1999</a></td>
    <td id="year2018"><a tabindex="0" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-placement="bottom" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="שנת 2018" data-content="מאז 'פוקימון' ועד היום האנימה ממשיכה לצבור פופולאריות בכל העולם וגם בישראל. עד היום יצאו מעל ל35,000  סדרות אנימה! ">2018</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```